# How to Automate if PDF is a part of a webpage (iframe) using Selenium?

Tags: selenium

I am trying to automate one of my functionality through selenium.

I have a Field, Report Number.

If Report number is entered by operator, it will bring out the patient name and id and below PDF is getting loaded as part of iframe..

Looks like that PDF is embedded as iFrame.

```
 <iframe id="pdfFrame" width="100%" height="800px" src="pdf.aspx?Template=&amp;ActionID=1"></iframe>
```

I wanted to enter the few fields like Doctor whom they want to meet, alloted time etc in the embedded pdf and once all details filled if i click send.. it will go to Doctor email and Patient email..

I can able to enter the report number in webpage.. But by swithcTo option can i enter the values in the PDF??? Because I need Xpath to enter it. But no clue to find the xpath for the pdf field.. Is it possible to do this or NOT??

Answer (score 1):

To enter the iframe you need to `driver.SwitchTo().Frame("iframe");` and you can then interact with the DOM in the iframe.
But in your case you want to interact with a PDF. Now the PDF content is not part of the DOM. The browser is rendering the PDF with it's own inbuilt tools and is not attached to the actual DOM so you will not be able to interact with the PDF using Selenium.

There is always the option of when you need to interact with the PDF you can use something like Microsoft's Coded UI or [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)

Comment: i am not sure AutoIt will help me. because i do have 3 pages pdf.. scroll down etc. should work or not.. that i dont know..  But one good thing is it can integrated with selenium..

Comment: @ChanGan try Coded UI

Comment: Coded UI, can i integrate with selenium??

Comment: @ChanGan Yes! You may have to change the Test attributes for Visual Studio to recognize it has some Coded UI e.g. [TestClass] = [CodedUITest]